# Using any() to stubbing before calling .thenReturn failing

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, any

My first question in StackOverflow. Tried to search for answer, but I could not find any related to my problem.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.scalatra.test.scalatest.ScalatraFunSuite
import org.mockito.Mockito.when
import org.mockito.Matchers.any

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
@Category(Array(classOf[DatabaseTest]))
class Test extends ScalatraFunSuite {

test("Test") {
  when(pre.findProduct(any[Seq[Sone]]))
    .thenReturn(Util.createProduct())
  when(ft.findProduct(any()))
    .thenReturn(Util.createFT())
  when(interval.findSones(any()))
    .thenReturn(Util.createInterval())

//The rest is code to utilise the above
}
```

I have the test code above written in Scala and using Mockito. Here is the error I get when I run it:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
>
> -> at org.Test.$anonfun$new$1(Test.scala:23)
>
> You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
>   Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
>       when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
>       doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
>       verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
>
> Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with
>   methods that cannot be mocked. Following methods *cannot* be
>   stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode(). Mocking methods
>   declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

That is, both `ft.findProduct(any())` and `interval.findSones(any())` get the same error. A temporarily fixed has been to use a fixed integer, that is:

```
test("Test") {
  when(pre.findProduct(any[Seq[Sone]]))
    .thenReturn(Util.createProduct())
  when(ft.findProduct(1))      //any() => 1
    .thenReturn(Util.createFT())
  when(interval.findSones(3))  //any() => 3
    .thenReturn(Util.createInterval())

//The rest is code to utilise the above
}
```

NOTE: Also tried to use `anyInt()`, which gave the same error.

My question is: Is there anything wrong with my code? Hope I was able to clarify my problem.

Comment: Can you post the function signatures for the three functions you're testing?

Comment: How `pre`, `ft` and `interval` are declared and created? Are they really mock objects? Also [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question would be very useful.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. This dumb example is a part of a big project for a company (and I'm a noobie who just started working there this year), and I'm not sure how to make a minimal example. Since there a lot of method call. It's still a dumb test which we will modify later, so I will try to find a solution (hopefully). But I really appreciate your response, thank you :) (Hope I did not use much of your time)